# Compiling on Windows using g++ and finding dependent .dlls

Tags: c++11, dll, g++, mingw

I'm making a 3D printer from scratch, hardware and software. I am using `mingw` to compile on windows and it works. But the .exe it produces relies on a bunch of .dlls in `mingw`'s bin folder. So that means that either I'm doing something wrong or just don't know which .dlls need to go with my .exe.

The command I run to compile is:

```
g++ -o Slicer.exe "d:\Programming And Creativity\Slicer\main.cpp" "d:\Programming And Creativity\Slicer\slice.cpp" "d:\Programming And Creativity\Slicer\face.cpp" "d:\Programming And Creativity\Slicer\line.cpp" "d:\Programming And Creativity\Slicer\vertex.cpp"
```

If I try going to my project's folder and running g++ from there, it complains about a bunch of missing files. How can I reduce the numer of dll's needed to run the exe file?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution to my problem, I just had to add the `--static` flag.